# I just installed Jenkins and lost my username. How do I find this?

Tags: jenkins

Yeah... it's a pretty dumb to do, but life happens.

Question... How do I find out my username for Jenkins if I forgot it? I'm not looking for password recovery; I wrote that down and it's safe. But, in the rush to get builds going, I forgot to write down the Jenkins user name.

I know I could just reset the the account completely, and there are plenty of search returns for that. But, I'd like to avoid that work if possible. Again, I have the password, just forgot the username.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew!

I found the answer.

1. Using a quick file and text parser (a la visual studio), I opened the complete `%JENKINS_HOME%` folder (your DevOps gal knows where this is) on a different computer with a known (and remembered) user name.
2. Then I searched for the known username.

The username is located in the `%JENKINS_HOME%/users/users.xml` file.

---

**tl;dr**

1. Go to %JENKINS_HOME%/users/users.xml
2. Look through here for the user name

Comment: Dont forget to accept your answer, so it doesnt show up as unanswered =)